# I cannot install any application anymore

Tags: software-installation, fonts

After installing wine and failed to agree on the agreement on the font.
this message is shown, and I cannot install or remove the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` anymore.

```
The package 'ttf-mscorefonts-installer' is in an inconsistent state and needs to be re-installed, but no archive can be found for it.
```

I use this command first to re install the 'ttf-mscorefonts-instaler'

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

This error message shows.

```
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.
```

and using this command "sudo apt-cache policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer" this error message shows.

```
Installed: 3.4ubuntu3
  Candidate: 3.4ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 3.4ubuntu3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.3ubuntu4 0
     500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages
```

and with this command "sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer" this message shows.

```
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ttf-mscorefonts-installer is broken or not fully installed
```

how to solve this problem??

Comment: Could you run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and tell us the output? note that is totally different that Mitch answer.

Comment: sorry i copied a wrong command.. but that is the output after entering the command line you gave me. ;)

Comment: Try using `sudo dpkg-reconfigure ttf-mscorefonts-installer` it may ask for the licence agreement again.

Comment: Please add `apt-cache policy ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

Comment: @Braiam this message is showing after I use your command.

"ttf-mscorefonts-installer:
  Installed: 3.4ubuntu3
  Candidate: 3.4ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 3.4ubuntu3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.3ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/multiverse amd64 Packages"

Comment: Good day. @Apurba this error message shows after using the command you gave me.. "Package `ttf-scorefonts-installer' is not installed and no info is available.
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: ttf-scorefonts-installer is not installed"

Comment: Please, always add the information on your question, is difficult reading in comments.

Comment: ok @Braiam I update my question again.. thank you for your help.

Comment: What's the output of `lsb_release -c`?

Comment: codename: oneiric

Comment: Maybe you can try downloading the oneiric version of ttf-mscorefonts-installer (the DEB file), and run it with gdebi. The link is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/oneiric/+package/ttf-mscorefonts-installer. Navigate to the bottom and select amd64/i386/other options and download the file on the next page.

Answer (score 1):

You should reinstall it, otherwise it won't get removed:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install -f
```

That should solve your issue.

Comment: good day. thanks for your reponse.
after using the first line of code, this error message shows.

"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

thanks.. hope you can recommend more command line to solve my problem.

Comment: Could you edit your question instead and add he  output?

Comment: I edited my question brother.. :) thanks for your response.

Comment: Nono, edit your question and include the output when you run the commands I gave you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get purge ttf-mscorefonts-installer
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Make sure you accept the agreement.

Comment: Good day.. thanks for your response.

after using the first line of code.
this error message shows.
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."

hope you can give more recommendation.

Comment: Have you tried the second line?  Also try rebooting your system, and then run this command in the Terminal `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Answer (score 0):

todionut's reply on thread [The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled - Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2207542) worked for me.

> I found a way solve the problem with this :
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get -f install
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```

Answer (score -1):

just reinstall

```
sudo apt-get install upgrade
```

when you reach at the menu, just type OK with the help of the <kbd>↹ TAB</kbd>  button.

So you can place a clear install, then everything will be ok. Just accept download policies (with the tab and press enter button). *Don't force close window* or it will break the procedure and crash.