# I am not able to open Update Manager

Tags: update-manager

I got this error message:

```
E:The package ttf-mscorefonts-installer needs to be reinstalled
```

but I can't find an archive for it. when I am trying to open Update Manager. What should I do?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/367274/i-cannot-install-any-application-anymore

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package by running the below command on terminal,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```